# How to check whether Autoscaling group was missing resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, eucalyptus

I have created few autoscaling groups, but for few of them I don't see any instances. How can I check if it is the not enough resources issue ?

Answer (score 1):

First check, what is the minimum number of instances you put for the autoscaling group. Then you can also look at the [Target Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html) for registered instances for the load balancer, whether there are any issues when running the instances.

Comment: There is also a **Scaling History** tab in the Auto Scaling group that explains why instances launched/terminated or failed to do so.